# how many light bulb for one relay?

Tags: relay, light

i've just done this tutorial: http://www.arduino.cc/es_old/Tutoriales/Rele

it works great! i've done it in a breadboard (with two 5v circuits for test) and then soldered (for just does not have 220v on a breadboard) and it works well for 1 light.

now i need more lights and i thought to make a relè for switch on/off a multiple adapter.

the thing i want to know: the pin of the relay are thin (just all other 5v-breadboard-based component) and i thought that more volts you have more bigger have to be the wire.. how many normal 220v ac light bulb can i control with one relay?

Comment: Can you give us the relay's specifications, preferably a datasheet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wire/pin thickness is not relevant to voltage, but to current. But even a 16 A relay will have thin pins, so that shouldn't be a problem.

What *is* something to take into account is that incandescent lamps cause a high **inrush current**, due to the fact that their resistance is low when they're cold. That inrush current may be as high as 10 \$\times\$ the nominal value. For instance, a 60 W bulb will draw 60 W/220 V \$\approx\$ 250 mA. Inrush current will be 2.5 A, then a 10 A relay will only switch four(*) 60 W bulbs, instead of the forty one might expect.

(*) *Strictly speaking even only three, if you take a 10 % tolerance on the mains voltage into account*

Comment: ok thanks. what can happen fif i plug more? and so what is the best way to do for more? use more relay?

Comment: @nkint - If you overload the relay the contacts will weld together, and it won't switch off anymore. More relays is a solution, or a special "high inrush current" relay. We had one type with custom contact material at work, but since it was custom that's not commercially available. But for instance the [Schrack RT1 Inrush Power relay](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=RT1_Inrush_Power&DocType=DS&DocLang=EN) is specified at 165 A inrush for 20 ms.